# Passing argument to handler function of addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

```
let hidden_button = 'hidden-button'

test_button.addEventListener('click', (hidden_button) => {
    alert(hidden_button);
    myFunc(hidden_button)
})
```

I want to pass an variable `hidden_button` to the handler. But when I do as above and print out the alert, it says `hidden_button` is a `MouseEvent`.
How do I pass arguments into the handler?
Does whatever in the brackets `() =>` refer to the event, which is a `click`? I found a few threads talking about `addEventHandler` but not the same problem I am looking at.
Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use hidden_button directly in the click event () => { ... use hidden_button ... }

Comment: @WilliamWang In my app, there is main button (i.e. ```test_button```) that is to trigger appropriate hidden elements to appear and apply ```myFunc``` on it. Here, that element is ```hidden_button```. So I can't do an ```addEventListener``` on the hidden button.

Comment: can you attach the minimum reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: just use the variable `hidden_button` inside the handler code ... you've declared it ... so it's available ... the first (and only) argument to an event handler is the `event` - so, you can't change that (without using bind) ... i.e. `test_button.addEventListener('click', (x) => {
    alert(x);
    myFunc(x)
}.bind(null, hidden_button))` - now `x` will be `hidden_button`

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks, This works now: ```let hidden_button = 'hidden-button'

test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(hidden_button);
    myFunc(hidden_button)
})```

Comment: that's exactly what @WilliamWang told you to do, so don't thank me

Comment: I see. I thought William was saying ```hidden_button.addEventListener```. Thanks both !